# Swift: table reloading on dimissviewcontrolleranimated from updateView to main View

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I have a CoreData project where:

-VC1 has a table of items. Clicking a cell invokes didSelectRowAtIndexPath func which leads to VC2 with presentViewController method.

-VC2 shows detail of the selected item. There is a button Edit which leads to VC3 where I can edit the details of the item and save, or another button to go back to VC1.

-From VC3 to VC2: When I edit the detail and save in VC3, VC3 will be dismissed, VC2 will reappear and the updated information is shown. No problem.

-From VC2 to VC1: When I press back button in VC2, VC2 will be dismissed, and VC1 is shown but the table Data are original ones and the updated detail/item is not shown. It will be shown only if I quit the app and rerun it.

I tested with print() to see if VC1's viewDidAppear(where I have the standard fetchAndResults and tableView.reloadData()) will kick in when returning back from VC2, and I noticed it doesn't print.

Does it mean VC1 is not disappeared when VC2 is presented with didSelectRowAtIndexPath func?

If so, how do I make VC1 to rerun its viewdidappear?

I tried to reload VC1's tableview from VC2 just before dismiss, but it gives me unexpected nil error.

Help me! Thanks.

Comment: OK, I figured out that the problem why VC1 is never actually disappeared is because I implemented self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext in VC2's viewDidLoad, in order to have a black transparent background effect over VC1. How can I achieve VC1's view "disappear" by keeping the transparent background of VC2?

Comment: Don't try to make VC1 "disappear" just to force the code in `viewDidAppear` to run when it reappears.  Move the code to another method.  Use a delegate pattern so VC2 can call this method to tell VC1 to reload its tableView.

Comment: Thanks pbasdf. I implemented protocol-delegate to run tableview reloaddata from VC2. Cheers!